# ¿Cuál sería el orden de resolver un problema cuando tienes multiplicación y división al mismo tiempo?

Tags: python

¿En qué orden resolverían esto?
Primero van por multiplicaciones y divisiones, pero cuál resuelvo primero.
16 - 2 * 5 // 3 + 1

Comment: que tal si abres una consola de python y escribes la operacion , esto te ayudaria mas a comprender el lenguaje tambien

Comment: te invito a leer [el orden de los operadores en python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Answer (score 2):

El [orden de precedencia](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) de los operadores es el siguiente:

- 1) Paréntesis y corchetes/llaves (listas, diccionarios/sets)
- 2) Indización, rebanado, llamada y referenciación de atributos.
- 3) Expresión `await`
- 4) Exponenciación (`**`)
- 5) Complemento/or binario, mas y menos unitarios `~ + -`
- 6) Multiplicación división, módulo, división entera y multiplicación de matrices (`* / % // @`)
- 7) Suma y resta (`+ -`)
- 8) Desplazamiento bit a derecha e izquierda (`>> <<`)
- 9) AND  binario (`&`)
- 10) XOR (OR exclusivo) binario (`^`)
- 11) OR binario (`|`)
- 12) Operadores de comparación (`<= < > >=`), operadores de igualdad (`== !=`) operador de pertenencia (`in`) y de identidad (`is`)
- 13) NOT lógico
- 14) AND lógico
- 15) OR lógico
- 16) Operadores de asignación (`= %= /= //= -= += *= **= :=`)

Para operadores con la misma precedencia se evalúan de izquierda a derecha (encadenado izquierda-derecha).

Por tanto, el orden de evaluación de tu expresión es el siguiente:

```
16 - [2 * 5] // 3  + 1
     |_____|
        |
16 -  [10    // 3] + 1
      |__________|
            |
16    -     3      + 1 
|___________|
      |
     13            + 1
      |______________|
              |
             14
```

**Ten presente que no es lo mismo aplicar la multiplicación antes o después de aplicar la división entera**, a diferencia de lo que ocurre con la división real:

- 16 - 2 * 5 // 3  + 1 = 14
- 16 - 2 * (5 // 3)  + 1 = 15

Esto se debe al truncado que lleva implícita la división entera:

- (2 * 7) // 2 = 14 // 2 = 7
- 2 * (7 // 3) = 2 * 2 = 4
- (2 * 7) / 2 = 14 / 2 = 7
- 2 * (7 / 2) = 2 * 3.5 = 7

Answer (score -1):

16-(2*5/3)+1, siempre se separan los términos en los + y los -.
2*5/3 no importa como lo pongas el resultado siempre es 3.333333...

Answer (score -1):

Si la pregunta es sobre programación, ademas de sabes que en papel y lápiz de grafito, primero debes resolver multiplicación o luego división (ojo si la ecuación lo permite) y luego suma o resta.

```
 Debes buscar Precedencia de operadores según tu lenguaje, aunque todos trabajan similar aquí te dejo el de la documentación de PhP:
```

https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.precedence.php