# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "if" y "if in"?

Tags: python, condiciones, comparaciones, formato-condicional

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `if` y el `if in`?

Sé que se puede hacer comparaciones lógicas en el `if`, pero no sé si se puede en el `if in`.

```
mensaje = " 34 56 87 4 23 12 32 3 4 68"
if '3' and '4' in mensaje:
    print("Sí")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La sentencia condicional `if`  básicamente evalúa una operación lógica, una expresión que da como resultado `True` o `False` y ejecuta el bloque de código que contiene si ésta se evalúa como verdadera.

`in` por su parte es un operador, se conoce como el operador de pertenencia (membership operator). Básicamente evalúa si un objeto es miembro de otro, si pertenece a otro. En el caso de secuencias evalúa por tanto si un valor existe en la secuencia o no. Retorna `True` si existe y `False` si no.

```
>>> 1 in [1, 2, 3]
True

>>> 5 in [1, 2, 3]
False

>>> "c" in "abcd"
True

>>> "f" in "abcd"
False

>>> "foo" in {"foo": 4}
True

>>> "bar" in {"foo": 4}
False
```

Por lo tanto, cuando se combina con `if` simplemente permite realizar algo si un valor está en la secuencia. `if` simplemente evalúa la expresión que le sigue, en este caso si `in` retorna `True` o `False` y ejecuta el bloque de código que contiene si retorna `True`.

```
l = [2, 3, 7]
n = int(input())

if n in l:
    print(f"¡El número {n} está en la lista!")
else:
    print(f"El número {n} no está en la lista....")
```

Por otro lado tenemos `not in` y que se define como el inverso de `in`,  retorna `True` si el valor no está en las secuencia y `False` si está:

```
l = [2, 3, 7]
n = int(input())

if n not in l:
    print(f"El número {n} no está en la lista....")
else:
    print(f"¡El número {n} está en la lista!")
```

Python intenta tener una sintaxis bastante legible para humanos, podemos traducir ambas condiciones por:

```
si n esta en l:
   haz esto

si n no está en l:
   haz esto
```

El operador `in` actúa de distintas formas dependiendo del objeto sobre el que se aplique:

- Para contenedores es equivalente a `any(valor is item or valor == item for item in contenedor)`
- Para cadenas sería algo similar a `cadena.find(valor) != -1`. Retorna `True` solo si el valor es una subcadena de la cadena.
- Para el resto de objetos intenta primero llamar al método especial `__contains__` del objeto, si no está implementado intenta iterar sobre `__iter__()` para ver si encuentra o no el item, en último caso lo intenta con `__getitem__()`.  Si nada es posible y no se ha generado una excepción previa, terminamos con una excepción el tipo:

  > TypeError: argument of type 'Objeto' is not iterable

Por tanto, podemos implementar `__contains__` en clases propias para sobrecargar el operador `in`, un ejemplo algo estúpido:

```
class Hotel:
    def __init__(self):
        self._habitaciones = {1: None, 2: None}
        
    def registrar_huesped(self, nombre):
        for hab, huesped in self._habitaciones.items():
            if huesped is None:
                self._habitaciones[hab] = nombre
                print(f"{nombre} registrado en habitación {hab} con éxito.")
                break
        else:
            print("Hotel completo...")
        
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return any(item == nombre for nombre in self._habitaciones.values())
```

> ```
> >>> hotel = Hotel()
> >>> hotel.registrar_huesped("Fulanito")
> Fulanito registrado en habitación 1 con éxito.
>
> >>> hotel.registrar_huesped("Menganito")
> Menganito registrado en habitación 2 con éxito.
>
> >>> hotel.registrar_huesped("Yo")
> Hotel completo...                # Maldita sea mi suerte....
>
> >>> "Menganito" in hotel
> True
>
> >>> "yo" in hotel
> False
> ```

---

Aparte de esto, en tu código ejemplo hay un error a tener en cuenta, el condicional:

```
if '3' and '4' in mensaje:
```

no es correcto, siempre retorna False, esto ocurre porque el [orden de evaluación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/337979/15089) de la expresión es:

```
 if ('3' and ('4' in mensaje)):
      |      |______________|
      |             |            
      |       (True / False) 
    True            |
      |_____________|
             |
       True and True/False
```

Primero se evalúa si "4" está en mensaje, luego se evalúa si "3" es cierto (que siempre lo es, ya que una cadena no vacía se evalúa como verdadera siempre). Por lo tanto, en la practica solo se comprueba si "4" está en la cadena, esté o no esté "3".

```
>>> mensaje = "4"

>>> if '3' and '4' in mensaje:
        print("Están")
    else:
        print("No están")

 Están
```

La expresión correcta es:

```
if "3" in mensaje and "4" in mensaje:
```

Comment: Hola @lalalisa, he editado la respuesta agregando una observación sobre un problema que se me pasó comentar en tu código de ejemplo, no se si fue un error tipográfico o un despiste al copiar tu código en la pregunta, pero si no lo es tu condicional no está bien formulado. Mira al final de mi respuesta que explico porqué. Un saludo.