# Comparar dos lista comparando los elementos en la misma posición (índice)

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, comparaciones, indices

Quiero comparar un indice de una lista con el indice de otra y así índice por índice

Por ejemplo, teniendo **dos listas de igual tamaño**, saber si el elemento `lista[0]` es igual al elemento `lista2[0]`, después comparar `lista[1]` con `lista2[1]` y así hasta completar toda la lista.

Este es el código que he intentado pero no entiendo el porque no funciona:

```
while contador<longuitud:
   contador += 1
   if lista1[contador] in lista2[contador]:
         print("si")
```

el error que me da es:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero unas observaciones sobre tu código:

- Si inicializas contador en 0 debes aumentar su valor después del condicional, o te saltarás el primer índice (0).
- Si quieres comparar indice por índice si los elementos en ese índice de ambas listas son iguales, para ello debes usar el operador de igualdad (==) y no el [operador de pertenencia (`in`)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/342021/15089). Dicho operador comprueba si un objeto pertenece o está contenido en otro, no si son iguales.

  > ```
  >  >>> "o" in "hola"
  >   True
  >   >>> "o" == "hola"
  >   False
  >   >>> 1 in 120
  >   TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
  > ```

El código podría quedar así:

```
lista1 = [2, 3, 1, 5, 7]
lista2 = [3, 3, 8, 5, 0]

longitud = len(lista1)
indice = 0
while indice < longitud:
    item = lista1[indice]
    if item == lista2[indice]:
       print(f"{item} se encuentra en ambas listas en el índice {indice}")
    indice += 1
```

Ten en cuenta que un ciclo `while` e indizado es una forma muy poco eficiente y pitónica de recorrer una lista, dicho ciclo es útil cuando no se conocen a priori el número de iteraciones, para todo lo demás un `for in` es la primera opción siempre.

La forma más eficiente y legible es usar `zip` para iterar a la par sobre ambas listas a la par:

```
for item1, item2 in zip(lista1, lista2):
    if item1 == item2:
        #....
```

`zip` genera un iterador que por cada iterable pasado va retornando tuplas que contienen un elemento de cada uno de los iterables, tomando un elemento de cada uno de ellos en cada iteración (llamada a `next`).

Si queremos también conocer el índice, podemos usar `enumerate`:

```
lista1 = [2, 3, 1, 5, 7]
lista2 = [3, 3, 8, 5, 0]

for indice, (item1, item2) in enumerate(zip(lista1, lista2)):
    if item1 == item2:
        print(f"{item1} se encuentra en ambas listas en el índice {indice}")
```

Comment: encontre que estaba mal en mi codigo, al estar el contador al principio de la orden aumentaba el valor antes de comparar y esto provocaba que se saliera del indice, gracias de igual forma no conocía ese metodo zip

Comment: Erick, he editado la pregunta, ten cuidado con `in`, no comparas si el item de la primera lista es **igual** al de la segunda, comparas si el elemento de la primera lista **está contenido** en el elemento de la segunda. Son dos cosas muy distintas. Ante enteros por ejemplo tendrá un bonito error, funciona con cadenas pero `"o" in "hola"` es verdadero... Si es lo que buscas perfecto, pero si no o es debes usar `==`. Un saludo.