# Validar caracteres repetidos consecutivamente en Python

Tags: python

Tengo una cadena de 72 caracteres en donde, el programa valida si es valida o no.
Es valida cuando el ultimo caracter es una "S" o una "E", tambien cuando no se repiten 3 "N" de forma consecutiva.

Por ejemplo.

**Nota:** La corte, pero se entiende que en verdad debe tener 72 caracteres.

WNEWSWNNNSNEWSWSEWSNSNNNWENW

Esa por ejemplo no es valida, porque tiene 3 "N" repetidas consecutivamente y 2 veces. Y no termina en "S" o "E". No necesariamente tiene que ser 2 veces repetida la letra N repetida en 3. Puede ser más o menos, el tema es que no se puede repetir 3 veces la N consecutivamente.

Hasta el momento logre validar primero que sea de 72 caracteres, y luego que valide que termine en "S" o "E". Pero no sé como validar que no debe repetirse consecutivamente la letra "N" 3 veces.

```
robot = str(input("Ingrese una secuencia de movimiento del robot [Único intento]: "))

if(len(robot) == 72):
    robot_1 = len(robot)
    last_robot = robot[robot_1-1]

    if(last_robot == "S" or last_robot == "E"):
        secuencia_valida = 1
        print("")
        print(secuencia_valida)
    else:
        print("")
        secuencia_invalida = 0
        print(secuencia_invalida)
else:
    print("")
    print("Error. Saliendo en 5 segundos...") 

time.sleep(5)
```

Eso, agradezco mucho la ayuda de esta comunidad. Quedo atento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es mucho más fácil de lo que parece si solo quieres descartar repeticiones del caracter `"N"`, usa el operador de pertenencia [in](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/342026/15089) sin más:

```
def es_valida(s):
    return len(s) == 72 and s[-1] in "SE" and "NNN" not in s
```

`"NNN" not in s` retornará `True` solo y solo si `"NNN"` no es una subcadena de `s`. Esta aproximación no te valdría si las repeticiones de más de 3 "N" fueran válidas, pero deduzco que no es el caso. Al usar `in` `"...WNNNNS"` sería también inválida.

Ten en cuenta que Python permite indizado negativo, `-1` el el último elemento del array, `-2` el penúltimo y así sucesivamente. `a[-1]` es el último carácter, no tienes que hacer malabarismos con `len` para calcular su índice positivo.

Comment: Gracias, por responder, una consulta amigo. Por un lado esta linea: ```return len(s) == 72 and s[-1] in "SE"``` Lo tomara como un "SE" al final, en vez de "S" o "E" por separado, como debe ser. Porque debe terminar en S o en E la secuencia, no SE juntos. Por otro lado voy a probar eso.

Comment: Aclarando,  `s[-1] in "SE"` comprueba si el último carácter (s[-1]) está en la cadena "SE", no valida que termine en "SE" por tanto, sino que termine en "E" **o** en "S". Sería similar a `len(s) == 72 and (s[-1] == "S" or s[-1] == " E") and "NNN" not in s`. Es igual que al hacer `"NNN" in s`, retorna `True` si "NNN" es una subcadena de `s`,  `s[-1] in "SE"` por su parte comprueba si `s[-1]` (cadena de un carácter) es una subcadena de "SE", de hecho es lo mismo que `s[-1] in "ES"` o `s[-1] in {"S", "E"}` o `s[-1] in ["S", "E"]`