# ¿Cómo utilizar radiobutton en Python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, sintaxis

[image: La imagen muestra la interfaz diseñada, donde el uso de los radiobuttons debe influir en el monto a ser pagado por las horas extra]
Me encuentro realizando un programa para determinar el salario neto de una persona. Para lo cual, la interfaz incluye radiobuttons para seleccionar si dicha persona realizó horas extra de día o de noche.
Cuestión que dependiendo de esto, se le agregará al salario x un extra, pero al intentar escribir el código correspondiente, el programa se cierra. (Sospecho que sea algún error en la sintaxis o algo así(?)).
La porción de código es la siguiente:

```
  def aceptar(self):
        sueldo = self.ui.TxtSueldo.toPlainText()
        extra = self.ui.TxtExtra.toPlainText()
        sueldo= int(sueldo)
        extra=int(extra)

        if (RdbDiurno==True) and (RdbNocturno==False):
            pago= 15000*extra
            self.ui.TxtPago.setText(str(pago))
            neto = sueldo+extra
        elif (RdbNocturno==True) and (RdbDiurno==False):
            pago=20000*extra
            self.ui.TxtPago.setText(str(pago))
            neto = sueldo+extra



        self.ui.TxtNeto.setText(str(neto))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dos cosas:

- `RdbDiurno` y `RdbNocturno` no son en principio (no lo muestras pero asumo que los creaste en QtDesigner) de `self.ui`. Para acceder a ellos necesitas hacerlo a través de su clase, los nombres `RdbDiurno` y `RdbNocturno` no existen es `self.ui.RdbDiurno` y `self.ui.RdbNocturno`.
- `RdbDiurno==True` es siempre `False` (obviando el error anterior). Lo que hace esta comparación es ver si el objeto asociado a `RdbDiurno` es igual a un objeto bool `True`, lo que obviamente no es cierto ya que es una instancia de `PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton`. Para saber si un `QRadioButton` está o no seleccionado debes usar el método `QRadioButton.isChecked()` que retorna `True` si lo está y `False` si no.

---

```
def aceptar(self):
    sueldo = self.ui.TxtSueldo.toPlainText()
    extra = self.ui.TxtExtra.toPlainText()
    sueldo = int(sueldo)
    extra = int(extra)

    if self.ui.RdbDiurno.isChecked() and not self.ui.RdbNocturno.isChecked():
        pago = 15000 * extra
        self.ui.TxtPago.setText(str(pago))
        neto = sueldo + extra
        self.ui.TxtNeto.setText(str(neto))
    elif not self.ui.RdbDiurno.isChecked() and self.ui.RdbNocturno.isChecked():
        pago = 20000 * extra
        self.ui.TxtPago.setText(str(pago))
        neto = sueldo + extra
        self.ui.TxtNeto.setText(str(neto))
```

Si los botones son exclusivos (solo puede haber uno seleccionado del grupo) y siempre hay uno seleccionado puedes simplificarlo:

```
def aceptar(self):
    sueldo = self.ui.TxtSueldo.toPlainText()
    extra = self.ui.TxtExtra.toPlainText()
    sueldo = int(sueldo)
    extra = int(extra)

    if self.ui.RdbDiurno.isChecked():
        pago = 15000 * extra
        neto = sueldo + extra

    else:
        pago = 20000 * extra
        neto = sueldo + extra

    self.ui.TxtNeto.setText(str(neto))
    self.ui.TxtPago.setText(str(pago))
```

Como nota aparte:

- Cuando quieras comprobar que una variable es evaluada como verdadera o no no uses:

  ```
   if foo == True:
   if foo != True:
  ```

  sino simplemente:

  ```
   if foo:
   if not foo:
  ```
- Si quieres saber si una variable es un objeto `bool` en concreto y no solo que se evalúa como cierta o no, usa [`is` (operador de pertenencia)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/342021/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-if-y-if-in/342026#342026):

  ```
   if foo is True:
   if not is not True:
  ```

---

```
>>> foo = 1
>>> bar = True

>>> foo is True
False
>>> bar is True
True
>>> if foo: print("foo es verdadera")
"foo es verdadera"
>>> if bar: print("foo es verdadera")
"bar es verdadera"
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Sigo teniendo malas costumbres de trabajar con VB, sos lo máximo. :)