# Ingresar números sin repetir y guarda lo en una lista en Python

Tags: python, bucle-for, arraylist, input

Quiero ingresar 5 números sin que se repitan y guárdalos en una lista hasta ahi en el código me guarda los 5 números en la lista pero no se como hacer para q no se repitan los números de la lista.

alguien me podría ayudar ? gracias de antemano

```
#Ingresar 5 números sin repetir y guarda los en la lista mi_jugada

mi_jugada=[]
for x in range(5):
  num=int(input(f"Ingrese el numero {x+1} de su jugada:"))
  mi_jugada.append(num)
print('Mi jugada es : ',mi_jugada)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La clave está en usar un ciclo `while` en vez de un `for` (dado que no sabes a priori cuantas veces el usuario puede ingresar un número ya presente en la lista) y usar el operador de pertenencia [`in`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/342026/15089) para saber si el número ya está agregado, si lo está se vuelve a pedir el número:

```
mi_jugada = []

x = 1
while x <= 5:
    num = int(input(f"Ingrese el numero {x} de su jugada: "))
    if num not in mi_jugada:
        mi_jugada.append(num)
        x += 1
    else:
        print("El número está repetido, inténtelo con otro...")
print('Mi jugada es : ', mi_jugada)
```

> ```
> Ingrese el numero 1 de su jugada: 5
> Ingrese el numero 2 de su jugada: 7
> Ingrese el numero 3 de su jugada: 3
> Ingrese el numero 4 de su jugada: 7
> El número está repetido, inténtelo con otro...
> Ingrese el numero 4 de su jugada: 13
> Ingrese el numero 5 de su jugada: 5
> El número está repetido, inténtelo con otro...
> Ingrese el numero 5 de su jugada: 3
> El número está repetido, inténtelo con otro...
> Ingrese el numero 5 de su jugada: 17
> Mi jugada es :  [5, 7, 3, 13, 17]
> ```

Comment: mucha gracias por tu ayuda , me funciono bien

Answer (score 0):

Validando si el numero a ingresar no esta en la lista

## Ingresar 5 números sin repetir y guarda los en la lista mi_jugada

```
mi_jugada=[]
for x in range(5):
  num=int(input(f"Ingrese el numero {x+1} de su jugada:"))
  if num not in mi_jugada:
    mi_jugada.append(num)
print('Mi jugada es : ',mi_jugada)
```